# MATLAB Runtime installer on Ubuntu

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler

I  try to install Runtime in MATLAB using the command

```
compiler.runtime.download
```

But I got the following error:

> Error using compiler.runtime.download
>   Unable to open output file:
>   '/home/amaa11/.mcrCache9.7/../MCRInstaller9.7/MATLAB_Runtime_R2019b_Update_4_glnxa64.zip' for writing. Common reasons include that the file exists and does not have write permission or the folder does not have write permissions.

Even I run MATLAB using `sudo command`, still got same error.
I tried to download it and then I install it, but still does not work.
How can this be solved?

Comment: Do you have a `/home/amaa11/MCRInstaller9.7` directory? As the error message says, it's possible this exists but doesn't have the right permissions. If a directory or a file is write-only, using `sudo` is not going to help you. You need to change the permissions on the directory and/or file.

Comment: Thanks so much. Yes I have it, How I change the permission ?

Comment: I did sudo chmod -R a+rwx MCRInstaller9.7/. But still got same error

Comment: Maybe just delete the directory: `rm -rf ~/MCRInstaller9.7`

Comment: I removed the directory, and restarted the PC, then run command again , it brings the directory again and got same error.

Comment: Weird! I have no idea what that could be, sorry.

Comment: Okay, thanks so much. You did  alot